# Missing a Syntax!? import CSV content, copy CSV to folder, delete original CSV

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax-error, read.csv

thanks for helping,

I want to run a script that inserts the contents A:AG of a csv file into an existing spreadsheet tab H:AO, then copy the csv file to another folder on my G-drive before deleting the original.

In my **CODE** I am getting an error that I cannot find and has become increasingly frustrating.

**"Syntax error: Missing ; before statement. line: 5 file: AutoCSVForecastImport."**

Any help in spotting my mistake(s) would be appreciated :)

**CODE:**

```
function importCSV() {
  const folderId = "1x-DByJyNvhiPD-1pJnsfm0cyt73_qRe1";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByName("CSV*");
  let latestFile = files.hasNext() ? files.next() : null;   // < --- the mystery problem line 5?!
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const latestModifiedTime = latestFile.getLastUpdated().getTime();
    const modifiedTime = file.getLastUpdated().getTime();
    if (modifiedTime > latestModifiedTime) {
      latestFile = file;
    }
  }
  if (!latestFile) {
    console.log("No CSV file found in the folder.");
    return;
  }
  const csv = latestFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auto CSV Forecast import");
  sheet.getRange("H:AR").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 7, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  row.setNumberFormat('#0');
  const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Kbetl4uPT2fEguHS_SUp-hpmUyPI62J5");
  latestFile.moveTo(destination);
  const pull = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  latestFile.setTrashed(true);
}
```

New CODE with sort array added

```
function importCSV() {
  const folderId = "1x-DByJyNvhiPD-1pJnsfm0cyt73_qRe1";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByName("CWF*");
  const fileArray = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fileArray.push(files.next());
  }
  if (fileArray.length === 0) {
    console.log("No CSV file found in the folder.");
    return;
  }
  fileArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.getLastUpdated().getTime() - a.getLastUpdated().getTime();
  });
  let latestFile = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
    const file = fileArray[i];
    if (file.getName().startsWith("CWF")) {
      latestFile = file;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!latestFile) {
    console.log("No CSV file found in the folder starting with CWF.");
    return;
  }
  const csv = latestFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auto CSV Forecast import");
  sheet.getRange("G1:AG").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 7, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  row.setNumberFormat('#0');
  const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Kbetl4uPT2fEguHS_SUp-hpmUyPI62J5");
  latestFile.moveTo(destination);
  const pull = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  latestFile.setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Your moving the iterator twice for each loop. I'd  remove this line `let latestFile = files.hasNext() ? files.next() : null;` and do it another way.  If your looking for the latest file I'd put them all in an array and sort the array by date

Comment: Your script reads `folder.getFilesByName("CSV*");`, but the error message refers to a file `AutoCSVForecastImport`. `folder.getFilesByName` doesn't accept wildcards. Which suggests that the script in the question is not the script that gave rise to the error message. What is the actual script? FWIW, I think that the error might be _in_ the file "AutoCSVForecastImport".

Comment: Thanks guys. The AutoCSVForecastImport is the name of the script. Have tried to resave the script as another file but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Cooper - i've given it ago but starting to get out of my depth. I seem to get the same type of error again but against line 16. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function importCSV() {
  const folderId = "1x-DByJyNvhiPD-1pJnsfm0cyt73_qRe1";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByName("CWF*");
  const fileArray = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fileArray.push(files.next());
  }
  if (fileArray.length === 0) {
    console.log("No CSV file found in the folder.");
    return;
  }
  fileArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.getLastUpdated().getTime() - a.getLastUpdated().getTime();
  });
  if (fileArray[0].getName().startsWith("CWF")) {
    latestFile = fileArray[0];
  }
  if (!latestFile) {
    console.log("No CSV file found in the folder starting with CWF.");
    return;
  }
  const csv = latestFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auto CSV Forecast import");
  sheet.getRange("G1:AG").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 7, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  row.setNumberFormat('#0');
  const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Kbetl4uPT2fEguHS_SUp-hpmUyPI62J5");
  latestFile.moveTo(destination);
  const pull = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  latestFile.setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Copper – Must be close, it's showing the error "No CSV file found in the folder". A CWF.csv file is there and the folder ID is definitely correct. I removed the *wildcard from the ("CWF*") and renamed the file to simply CWF but it still doesn't see it... do I need to declare the latestFile variable for any reason before it's assigned?

Comment: I would declare it

Comment: I tried this but produces the original error again.  ...const fileArray = [];
  let latestFile = null; // <-- Declared latestFile
  while (files.hasNext()) { ... can't get my head around it!